# r- Feed a list of variables into a matrix for a t.test

Tags: r

```
replicate(10, rnorm(20))-> ExampleData

x<-2
ExampleData[x,7:9]->Example1
ExampleData[x,3:5]->Example2

t.test(Example1, Example2)
```

I would like to know how to feed a list of variables into "x". Like:

```
c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

and then get the results from the t.test back.

Comment: that gives me an average of the five in the t.test. I want 5 separate t.tests.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661469/r-t-test-over-all-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741886/how-to-run-multiple-t-test-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a loop

```
ExampleData <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
temp=c(2,3,4,5,6)
for(x in temp){

  ExampleData[x,7:9]->Example1
  ExampleData[x,3:5]->Example2

  print(t.test(Example1, Example2))

}
```

this will produce a t-test for each value in the temp-vector

Comment: Unfortunately this only provides me one t-test that is an average. Unless I am missing a command to make it print all 3 t-tests. Thanks!

Comment: 3 t tests?, you have 5 numbers in that vector..So you should be expecting 5 t-tests. You will need to add the results of each t-test to a vector. You are most likely only seeing the result of the last t-test.

Comment: how do I print the other 4?

Comment: print(t.test(Example1, Example2))
I've just tested this with replicated data and it prints 5 t-tests.

Comment: `> print(t.test(Example1, Example2))`

 `Welch Two Sample t-test`

`data:  Example1 and Example2`
`t = -0.7379, df = 3.3481, p-value = 0.5089`
`alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0`
`95 percent confidence interval:`
` -3.073777  1.861241`
`sample estimates:`
 `mean of x  mean of y `
`-0.3863355  0.2199328`  This is the only result I recieve

Comment: I’m not sure what to tell you if you look at the logic of the loop there is nothing wrong you loop five times printing a T test each time with a different number supplemented for x. You have to brainstorm and play around a little bit but it’s a very simple approach.   Copy and paste my answer into R and run it and then tell me if it only printed one result.

Comment: You do know that you have to write that print command within the loop right?

Comment: Yeah... it worked after doing that. Thank you for the help. The documentation on loops wasnt particularly helpful.